# Prefix Decrement vs Subtract Used in Recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I would like to find out why when I change n - 1 to --n, the function will throw an exception.
from my understanding, --n and n - 1 produces the same result. See Print(). Please help. Thank you.

```
    private static void Print(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return;

        Console.Write($"[{n}] -> ");
        // regardless of --n or n--, the results are the same.
        Print(n - 1);
    }

    private static double KnapSack(int maxWeight, Product[] products)
    {
        double maxValue = KnapSack(maxWeight, products, products.Length);
        Console.WriteLine($"The max value the knapsack can hold is: {maxValue:C2}");
        return maxValue;
    }
    private static double KnapSack(int maxWeight, Product[] products, int n)
    {
        if (n == 0 || maxWeight == 0)
            return 0;

        if (products[n - 1].Weight > maxWeight)
            return KnapSack(maxWeight, products, n - 1);

        else return Max
        (
            // if we change n - 1 to --n, it will throw an exception.
            products[n - 1].Price + KnapSack(maxWeight - products[n - 1].Weight, products, n - 1),
            KnapSack(maxWeight, products, n - 1)
        );
    }
```

Comment: `--n` *changes* `n`. `n-1` just computes a new value but doesn't store it in `n`.

Answer (score 2):

If you changed all 3, then each time it decrements again and again. So it becomes n-1, n-2, and n-3.

In other words, n-1 doesn't mutate n. But --n does.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your reply. Use for an example, Print(int 3), if i call --n, Print(= 2) , doing so with n - 1 will yield the same results. So, I don't understand when you mentioned, --n mutates but n - 1 does not mutate.

Comment: @SherNing [Check this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gues2W). Notice how the value of `a` never changes, but the value of `b` repeatedly decreases. That's the difference. "mutating" means that the value changes, which is what is happening for `b` in the example but not for `a`.

Comment: @SherNing - They _appear_ to give the same result in your particular example, but they do different things. You can have `n = 3` then do `Print(n-1)` a million times, and guess what `n` would be? Still 3. But if you have `n = 3` then do `Print(--n)` a million times, guess what. `n` will be -999,997.